# Problem with C# SDK ver 5 -

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to run the MVC website sample and running into this problem;
`Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error in regular expression`

`var a=document.cookie.match('\\bfbs_'+FB._apiKey+'="([^;]*)\\b'`

What am I dong wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

The document.cookie.match() is unclosed.  There seems to be a trailing " that isn't present (at a guess) and also the FB._apiKey may contain some reserved characters that need escaping.